# Is there any way to close Angular UI tooltip by clicking outside it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

In order to get this ability i have extended tooltip provider.

```
function customTooltip($document, $tooltip) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('customTooltip', 'customTooltip', 'click'),
        parentCompile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);

    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {
        var parentLink = parentCompile(element, attrs);

        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var firstTime = true;

            parentLink(scope, element, attrs);

            var onDocumentClick = function () {
                if (firstTime) {
                    firstTime = false;
                } else {
                    element.triggerHandler('documentClick');
                }
            };

            var bindDocumentClick = function () {
                $document.on('click', onDocumentClick);
            };

            var unbindDocumentClick = function () {
                $document.off('click', onDocumentClick);
            };

            scope.$watch('tt_isOpen', function (newValue) {
                firstTime = true;

                if (newValue) {
                    bindDocumentClick();
                } else {
                    unbindDocumentClick();
                }
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function onTooltipDestroy() {
                unbindDocumentClick();
            });
        };
    };

    return tooltip;
}
```

But this approach doesn't work already because there is no tt_isOpen property in scope now. Actually i can't see any of tooltip properties just only my parent scope. I guess this happend because of changes in tooltip.js 124 line https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L124. Is there any way now to close tooltip by clicking outside it or at least to get isOpen flag?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114361/4572425

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/4419) that implements an `outsideClick` trigger for tooltips and popovers. It will be included in angular-ui 1.0.0, which is expected to be released by the end of the year. Once it is implemented, you will be able to simply add `tooltip-trigger="outsideClick"` to your element.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open pull request [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2148) to add this feature.  A hack workaround you can try is to disable then enable the trigger element as the directive will call this method:

```
        attrs.$observe( 'disabled', function ( val ) {
          if (val && ttScope.isOpen ) {
            hide();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant works on angular 1.3.15 and angular-ui version 0.13

```
function customTooltip($document, $tooltip) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('customTooltip', 'customTooltip', 'click'),
        parentCompile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);

    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {

        var parentLink = parentCompile(element, attrs);

        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

            parentLink(scope, element, attrs);

            var isOpened = false;

            element.bind('click', function () {
                bindDocumentClick();
            });

            var onDocumentClick = function () {
                if (!isOpened) {
                    isOpened = true;
                } else {
                    element.triggerHandler('documentClick');
                    unbindDocumentClick();
                    isOpened = false;
                }
            };

            var bindDocumentClick = function () {
                $document.on('click', onDocumentClick);
            };

            var unbindDocumentClick = function () {
                $document.off('click', onDocumentClick);
            };

            scope.$on('$destroy', function onTooltipDestroy() {
                unbindDocumentClick();
            });
        };
    };

    return tooltip;
}
```