# ui.bootstrap popover close on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this popover with template

```
<i class="fa fa-link" popover-placement="right" uib-popover-template="'newReferenceTemplate.html'" popover-title="New link"> Add new external reference </i>
```

So when I click on that link icon, a popover opens witht this tamplate

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="newReferenceTemplate.html">
  <label>Title</label> <br>
  <input ng-model="link.Title"> <br>
  <label>Url</label> <br>
  <input ng-model="link.Url"><br>
  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" > Save </i>
</script>
```

When I press that 'floppy' icon, I'd like to close the popover. Are there any ways of doing this?

All I can find [on documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) is the `popover-is-open` value, but I don't know if I can use this somehow, any thoughts?

Comment: Found a plunkr that does just that: http://plnkr.co/edit/QhshtRqwpdsirvdFj9JG?p=preview

Comment: That is... a lot of code for just that, I will try and decipher it and see what I come up with, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Add `popover-is-open="isOpen"` to the trigger link.

```
<i class="fa fa-link add-link" 
        popover-placement="right" 
        uib-popover-template="'newReferenceTemplate.html'" 
        popover-is-open="isOpen"
        popover-title="New link"> Add new external reference </i>
```

**Step 2 :** When you click the floppy icon inside the popover, set `isOpen` to false:

This is the save icon of the popover:

```
<i class="fa fa-floppy-o" ng-click="save()"> Save </i>
```

This is in the controller:

```
$scope.save = function () {
  $scope.isOpen = false;  
};
```

See **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7FhoxmWtNFAHVvn6yIwY?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

What had worked for me (in an angularJs app) is using

> popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"

be aware to use it as it is, means, hard copy of string

> "'outsideClick'".

If u don't use angularJs, u can just write:

> popover-trigger="outsideClick"

Example:

```
<div uib-popover-template="'ApproveReject.html'"
     popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"
     popover-placement="bottom-right"
     ng-click="onSubmitOrderStatus('date',$event);approveDates('date')">
    Approve
</div>
```